# Lollipop theme on Android KitKat

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, customization

I have a Dell Venue 8 running Android 4.4.2 KitKat. I want my Android to look like Lollipop *without rooting*, from status-bar to navigation keys, everything like Lollipop.

Comment: This device seems to have a lollipop update from OEM. Is there a reason you want to theme but not update to Lollipop?

Comment: I have 3830 update is for 3840.

Answer (score 2):

Thats not possible. Not without root. Even with root there is no mod to turn that navigation panel as you said (atleast no universal verified mod).
You can change navigation keys though. Again, not without root.

At best, you can install some custom launcher and make homescreen icons and style look like lollipop, nothing beyond that.

Comment: Let me declare what I have already Google launcher,android apps updated to material design, google keyboard, material peoples app, lollipop lock screen,material wallpaper.

Comment: Yup, and additional launcher and icons are only customization you can do further. Since modifying any system elements (for ex the notification panel, statusbar, navigation bar etc etc) require system files modding which needs root.

Comment: But super status bar? Don't forget about it.

Comment: Yes there are a good bunch of similar apps. Besides super status bar theres omega status bar a lot of similar apps too. But they simply make an overlay on your current statusbar. In other words, they dont modify anything, but instead try to overdraw on them. Hence more than70% of times it wont work because android doesn't allow overdrawing system elements that easy.... You can clearly see that from reviews of that app. So if I were you, I wouldnt rely on these apps.. Again, you can always give them a shot ;)

Comment: But they don't really have lollipop theme, looks like their is wait for update.